# Honda CBX 1979 Regulator/Rectifier - Lipo (lifepo4) battery

Tags: voltage-regulator, connector, rectifier, alternator

I exchanged the OEM battery (PB) of the CBX 1000 motorcycle with a Lifepo4 12V battery.  It is smaller, lighter and has a much better CCA.  However, the connector (wires at the bottom side of photo) between the rectifier and the alternator now gets extremely hot (some times smoking hot). This was not the case with the OEM battery.  The connector is about 200 mm from the rectifier.  The rectifier heats up like normal. The alternator is 100%, charging about 14.5V. The lipo battery is 13.6V fully charged and the OEM (PB) reads 12.8V fully charged.  How do I look and rectify the heat issue in the plug? The plug wires are clean and the connection between the male and female side is good.

Is it correct to assume that the regulator shunts the alternator's output to a "fixed" voltage?

See included photos:

[image: Diagram 1]
Regulator Diagram

[image: connector]
The connector that gets hot - only the bottom side wires get very hot

[image: Diagram 2]

Battery:

[image]

Comment: Which exact LiFePo battery make/model you bought and can you give a link to datasheet?

Comment: It is a NovelBat - 12V, 72WA, CCA 360

Comment: tas the first battery Lead Acid? The data sheet you linked to does not give charging information, do you have more information?

Comment: Yes the original battery was a lead acid.  I built a Cafe Racer and need a smaller battery that can be placed on its side, it must have sufficient CCA and be light weight - hence the Lipo.

Answer (score 2):

Don’t do this.

The charging circuit is designed for the lead acid battery.

The wires overheating are signs of too much current flowing - this will either cause the alternator to fail or the lipo battery to fail or worse catch fire.

Answer (score -2):

I wonder if your voltage regulator could be bad, and pushing too much voltage to the battery? I didn't bother pouring through your schematics to really figure it out, but if it were my bike, here's what I'd do to verify charging voltage:

1. Get a good DMM with good batteries, so you know it's accurate.
2. Start the bike and let it idle.
3. Measure & write down the battery voltage while idling.
4. Rev engine to 2k RPM, measure & write down battery voltage.
5. Disconnect the negative terminal***
6. Measure & write down the voltage between the bike side battery terminals while idling.
7. Slowly Rev engine to 2k RPM, measure & write down voltage between the bike side battery terminals. Stop if the voltage climbs above 16volts.
8. I'd also feel that harness and see if it still gets hot with the engine running, and battery disconnected.

Report back to us your measurements.

*** Before some of you jump on me saying " OMG! NEVER DISCONNECT THE BATTERY WHILE IT'S RUNNING!!!!"
Think about it...... Is it possible for a battery to have an internal fault, where one of the cells totally dries out, or gets disconnected? What's makes a battery go bad, and not take a charge? Typically high internal impedance? Have you ever personally witnessed internal combustion engine electronics die, because the battery was disconnected while running? I believe that's an old wives tail that gets perpetuated by people who don't understand.

However..... I would be careful and watch the charging voltage closely while *slowly* revving up to 2k, with the battery disconnected. If it climbs over 16v I'd suspect a bad voltage regulator.

https://www.fullspectrumpower.com/blogs/full-spectrum-news/tech-talk-can-i-use-a-lithium-motorcycle-battery-in-my-bike

Comment: Yes, have had customers be **very** unhappy when they needed to purchase a new alternator after disconnecting the battery. I was happy - I got the profit of selling it :)  Suggest you be more careful with advice, should be based on experience.

Comment: Ok, my ears are open, and I'm ready to listen. How does an alternator self-destruct without a battery in circuit?

Comment: I doubt that the regulator is bad as it acts very normal with the original lead acid battery.  With the OEM battery I measure 12.6 V and when started up and rpm is about 2500 the V go to 14.5... which is normal.  With the Lipo battery installed I measure 13.6 V and started up and rpm is about 2500 it is still about 14.5 V.

Comment: Huh. That is weird. The only thing that I can think of is that lipos are typically shipped partially charged, and if your bike hasn't been running long, it probably draws a large current until it's charged to a full state.   I'm unfamiliar with lipo drop in batteries for motorcycles. But I'm guessing there is some sort of charge controller built into the battery itself.

Comment: Yes, the battery has its own cell management and over charging protection.... The battery came fully charged.

Comment: "Is it correct to assume that the regulator shunts the alternator's output to a "fixed" voltage?" To answer your original question, yes fixed voltage, unless the motor speed is low, and the stator windings can't generate enough voltage to get to the set point.    The voltage regulator determines how much power goes you the exciter winding, by monitoring the alternator output voltage.          Do you have a DMM capable of measuring DC Amps? I'm curious how many amps are going to the lipo battery when running.

Comment: I also find it weird that you mention only the bottom half of the Molex connector gets hot. That leads me to believe that there's a loose crimp inside the bottom Molex connector. If you Google "removing Molex pins" you could take them out individually and check the crimps to the wires. It's also possible that there's broken copper strands inside the bottom wire.

Comment: Thanks Mike B - I will investigate!!